# Should seperate Task Lists and History Lists be created for each workflow?

Tags: 2010, workflow, task-list, workflow-history

When creating Workflows, you have the option of creating new Task List for the Workflow or using an existing Workflow task list.  The same type of option is available for the History list of the workflow.

My question is then, is it better to re-use the same Task List and History List for all Workflows in the site?  Or should a new task and history list be created for each workflow?  Are there benefits or drawbacks to one approach or the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how big they will get, but I would create a different workflow history moreover than the tasks list. Usually it is best practice if they will be used heavily. The drawbacks are that the tasks are not all in one place, so some tasks will have to be cross referenced inside workflows. The benefit is that if a task list need to have different settings (i.e. email upon assigning a task; security; different columns), then you have that ability. All those factors are something you would have to address and identify.